# Is using Moq pointless, since Returns() redefines the behavior of your method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to familiarize myself with TDD. I am trying to figure out how to use Moq alongside with NUnit. I have created an ICalculator interface that has an Add(decimal num1, decimal num2) method and a Calculator class that implements it.

My problem is, by specifying what should be returned when specific values are in, am I essentially not redefining the way my method works? I mean, if I were to suddenly make the Add method multiply the numbers instead, my test would still not break as I have changed the way it works completely.

Am I missing something obvious about the purpose of Moq and how it should be used?

```
 var mockCalculator = new Mock<ICalculator>();
 mockCalculator.Setup(mock => mock.Add(10m, 25m)).Returns(35m);
 var calculator = mockCalculator.Object;

 var result = calculator.Add(10m, 25m);

 Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(35m));
```

I also tried following the article [here](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/mocking-with-moq/), but it ends up doing the same thing - predefining the result which won't change even if the method being tested does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point of mocking isn't to mock the central code you're testing, but to mock its dependencies. This works best when the dependencies are interfaces. Let's say you have this interface:

```
public interface IFileLoader {
    string loadFileContents(string fileName);
}
```

and a class that implements it by actually opening and reading from that file. Then, you have another class which uses that class:

```
public class FileAnalyzer {
    private readonly IFileLoader _fileLoader;

    public FileAnalyzer(IFileLoader fileLoader) {
        _fileLoader = fileLoader;
    }

    public string Analyze(string fileName) {
        String contents = _fileLoader.loadFileContents(fileName);
        // (Some fancy algorithm here, resulting in some return value)
    }
}
```

Now, you want to test `FileAnalyzer.Analyze()`, which presumably contains some advanced logic. Actually having to create a file on disk and passing it to that method during the test would be cumbersome; it would be easier to simply keep the input string in a variable. With a mocking framework, you can mock the dependency `FileLoader`, thus being able to concentrate on testing the actual logic.

```
[Test]
public void TestAnalyze() {
    var mockLoader = new Mock<IFileLoader>();
    mockLoader.Setup(ml => ml.loadFileContents("foo.txt")).Returns("Whatever you would have had in the file");
    var analyzer = new FileAnalyzer(mockLoader.Object);
    Assert.That(analyzer.Analyze("foo.txt"), Is.EqualTo("Expected analysis result"));
}
```

This test doesn't touch the file system at all, and is therefore simpler and faster. In the production (non-test) code, you would use a real implementation of `IFileLoader` that actually reads the file from disk: `new FileAnalyzer(new RealFileLoader())`. Also, notice that `FileAnalyzer` doesn't need to know about files or the fact that its data will come from a file when running in production and from a string when running in the test.

Comment: But in this scenario, let's say the logic of Analyze changed and instead it was meant to return only a small part of the whole "Expected analysis result" value. The behavior of Analyze would be different, but the test would still pass just fine, as the return value is hard-coded in. Does that not go against the whole idea of unit testing?

Comment: @EvilBeer: No, the test would fail. If `Analyze` returned only the first word ("Expected"), then the test would fail because you're expecting "Expected analysis result". What Aasmund is saying is that you're testing the _interface_ when you should be testing the _implementation_. (In your test, there is no implementation of `ICalculator`. You should be testing a concrete _class implementation_ at some point.)

Comment: I might be being an idiot right now, but what I'm saying is, if you changed the .Returns() to return ("Expected"), then the test would still pass - as far as the test is aware, that is the correct implementation. So I guess what I'm saying is, if you manually specify the exact input and the exact output, even if the actual Analyze() method was just to return String.Empty, your test would have no way to be aware of that change, right? (As according to its .Returns() implementation, it is functioning fine)

Comment: @EvilBeer: The string you specify in `Returns()` is what will be _given by the mock to `Analyze()`_, whereas what you assert on is _the return value of `Analyze()`_. So if you change `Analyze()` without changing the mock value or the expected value accordingly, the test will fail because `Analyze()` now produces a different result based on the same input from the mock.

Comment: Ahh, I think I finally got it. Thanks a lot, you both :)

Comment: @EvilBeer: By the way - even though you were misunderstanding it at first, that doesn't make you "an idiot" :-)